# Get the full word that cursor is touching (or within) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, range

With a native input field I can get the cursor's position just fine. Also any highlighted text easy enough.

```
// get cursor position
console.log(input.selectionStart);
// get highlighted text
console.log(input.value.substr(input.selectionStart, input.selectionEnd - input.selectionStart));
```

But how can we get the full word that the cursor is touching?

`this is a |sent|ence|`

**Question:**

If each pipe is a potential cursor position, arrow keyed or clicked in-and-around a word, how can we get the full word "sentence"?

**Sub questions:**

1. Range or RegEx for this solution?
2. Can RegEx lookaround by position in a string?
3. Can Regex find the word if given character position in a string

Research:
https://javascript.info/selection-range.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/caretRangeFromPoint (Chrome only)

Working [CodePen with RegEx](https://codepen.io/BRacicot/pen/YzyYYGm?editors=1010) from a friend.

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed example with html + js code? Also, I looked at your links, it seems Range is doing what you are looking for. I would push on this personally. Finally, have you looked for a polyfill/library which would ease your task and make it eventually cross-browser?

Comment: Thank you @FlorentRoques for the positive and helpful comment, all too rare on SO. I've posted an answer which works. However I'm not sure if it's the ultimate solution for finding words or if the `tool for the job` exists with ranges. (I've read all those links through twice)

Comment: Ranges do not apply for <input> fields so nope, not the tool you want.

Comment: Hey @Kaiido check the links. I/we are currently using them for inputs just fine.

Comment: ... Ranges do not apply for <input> fields. Either you're not using an <input>, either you're not using a [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range) For text input you can use their `selectionStart`, `selectionEnd` values, but Ranges won't have access to <input> values . https://jsfiddle.net/x15a7dek/

Comment: Yes Ranges are used on elements and text nodes only, that's correct, but inputs have another API which includes some of the same tooling such as  `setSelectionRange` and `setRangeText` etc. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#textFieldSelection

Comment: So... Ranges is not the tool you want.

Comment: Well @Kaiido using the API for inputs that is based on the Ranges spec do you have anything to add to this question?

Comment: It isn't. There is like none of the methods of the Range API available there. Your question asks how to use Ranges for your case. I'm pointing out that you don't because Ranges don't handle input fields.

Comment: Do you want to get the word around caret in `contenteditable`s?

Comment: Hey @OrkhanAlikhanov no that's not a requirement, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido I understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 13):

You may use some regex to look for

- any string containing word character ending at `position`
- any string containing word character starting from `position`

```js
const [$show, $input] = document.querySelectorAll('span,textarea')
const getWord = (s, pos) => {
  const n = s.substring(pos).match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/)
  const p = s.substring(0, pos).match(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/)
  // if you really only want the word if you click at start or between
  // but not at end instead use if (!n) return
  if(!p && !n) return ''
  return (p || '') + (n || '')
}
const showWord = e => $show.innerText = getWord(e.target.value, e.target.selectionStart)
$input.addEventListener('click', showWord)
$input.addEventListener('input', showWord)
```

```css
textarea{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<span id="inputshow"></span><br/>
<textarea>In computer science, an x-fast trie is a data structure for storing integers from a bounded domain. It supports exact and predecessor or successor queries in time O(log log M), using O(n log M) space, where n is the number of stored values and M is the maximum value in the domain. The structure was proposed by Dan Willard in 1982,[1] along with the more complicated y-fast trie, as a way to improve the space usage of van Emde Boas trees, while retaining the O(log log M) query time. </textarea>
```

Comment: Really impressive @grodzi this may be the most efficient. I applied to my CodePen setup and it works great.

Comment: `p` and `n`   are `RegExpMatchArray`s. So it seems we need `p[0] + n[0]`.

Comment: edit: tldr, you can write p[0]+n[0] but it is not necessary. It is a bit subtle: In case I match, the array is of the form ['matched', index: 5] ([see](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexpbuiltinexec)). When using the addition, array is coerced as string, and ... toString on this array relies on ArrayIteratorPrototype [ @@toStringTag] which iterates over the [length] properties of that array. Since I captured noone (no parenthesis groups), the array is length 0 + 1, and we only get the first result that is 'matched'

Comment: Got it, it seems TS has a bad application of the RegExpMatchArrays spec.
This works for TS `return <string>(p || '') + (n || '');`

Answer (score 4):

If you define "a word" as any succession of characters delimited by a space character, then you can simply use `String.prototype.lastIndexOf` and `String.prototype.indexOf` searching for a space character before and after your cursor's position, and then getting the substring from this range:

```js
const inp = document.querySelector('input');
document.onselectionchange =
  inp.onselect = inp.onclick = // Firefox doesn't fire selectionchange in <input>
    (evt) => {
  const text = inp.value;
  const start_index = inp.selectionStart;
  const end_index = inp.selectionEnd;
  const previous_space_index = text.lastIndexOf( " ", start_index - 1 );
  const next_space_index = text.indexOf( " ", end_index );
  const begin = previous_space_index < 0 ? 0 : previous_space_index + 1;
  const end = next_space_index < 0 ? text.length : next_space_index;
  const between_spaces = text.substring( begin, end );

  console.log( between_spaces );
};
```

```html
<input type="text" value="this is a sentence">
```

If you really need to define "a word" as any succession of characters matching `/\w/`, then it's a bit more convoluted:

```js
const inp = document.querySelector('input');
document.onselectionchange =
  inp.onselect = inp.onclick = // Firefox doesn't fire selectionchange in <input>
    (evt) => {
  const text = inp.value;
  const start_index = inp.selectionStart;
  const end_index = inp.selectionEnd;
  // search in the before substring 
  const before_text = text.substring( 0, start_index );
  // for all non word characters
  const before_match = before_text.match( /\W/g );
  // get the last one
  const last_before_match = before_match && before_match[ before_match.length - 1 ];
  // retrieve its index
  const previous_nonword_index = last_before_match ? text.lastIndexOf( last_before_match, start_index - 1 ) : -1;
  const begin = previous_nonword_index < 0 ? 0 : previous_nonword_index + 1;
  
  // search in the after substring 
  const after_text = text.substring( end_index );
  // for the first occurence of a non word character
  const next_nonword_index = after_text.search( /\W/ );
  // remember to add the length of the beginning string to the found index
  const end = next_nonword_index < 0 ? text.length : next_nonword_index + end_index;
  
  const between_spaces = text.substring( begin, end );
  console.log( between_spaces );
};
```

```html
<input type="text" value="this undefined is a sæntence wîth nøn word characters" size="40">
```

Comment: Great answer @Kaiido, are you saying that this can be done without RegEx? Is this more efficient that say Grodzi's solution below?

Comment: @BenRacicot Their solution is good too, at least probably better than my second snippet. Now which is more performant between the RegEx and String methods entirely depends on the input (the tested text): its size, the kind of characters etc will make dramatic changes for both methods. If you know what kind of input you'll get, then perform benchmarks on samples and choose the least worse  ;-)

Comment: I think you are being modest @Kaiido . perf wise your string search is faster than my regexs. This indeed ... would need proof but it seems irrelevant to me: I think the problem lies more in the 'what character set defines the delimiters' rathen than perfs. All in all it is great to have variants

Comment: I wanted to thank you for this answer Kaiido. It may even be the best answer and I truly appreciate the work you've put in. However Grodzi's is what I ended up using and thus I awarded him the bounty.

Comment: @BenRacicot you did very well, their answer deserves the bounty at least as much as this one, and they probably  need more of these Unicorn Points than I do (I already have all the moderation tools I can win)

Answer (score 2):

First, assume all non-word characters as a pipe, then expand the caret offset into the nearest pipe character position.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // We only need the character offset here
    // Assume all non-word character(s) is a pipe
    let test = this.value.replace(/\W/g, '|');
    let caret = this.selectionStart;
    // Get the last word part length before caret
    let indexBeforeCaret = test.substring(0, caret).split('|').pop().length;
    // Get the first word part length after caret
    let indexAfterCaret = test.substring(caret).split('|')[0].length;
    // let word = this.value.substring(caret - indexBeforeCaret, caret + indexAfterCaret);
    // console.log(word);
    // Expand current caret position to the whole word
    this.selectionStart = caret - indexBeforeCaret;
    this.selectionEnd = caret + indexAfterCaret;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="this is another sentence!">
```

Comment: Hey @TaufikNurrohman This is very creative but I cannot get it working with the CodePen. Can you apply it to the testing setup there? https://codepen.io/BRacicot/pen/WNQJzgL

Comment: The selected word is stored in the `word` variable that I have commented at line 12. Put that variable value somewhere in the HTML. And based on your example, it should be done with `document.getElementById('word').textContent = word;`

Answer (score 2):

Browser API provides a dead simple solution which does not require traversal or regex:

```js
const selection = window.getSelection();

// Move cursor to beginning of the word
selection?.modify('move', 'backward', 'word');

// Extend selection to the end of the word
selection?.modify('extend', 'forward', 'word');

// Get the word
selection.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my own answer, albeit it does not answer the Ranges question. That is still up in the air.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/BRacicot/pen/YzyYYGm?editors=1010)

```
// Thanks to Yash Mathur for this solution
public getWordAtNthPosition(str: string, position: number) {
    if (!/^[A-Z]|^[0-9]|\s$/i.test(str[position])) {
        return null;
    }
    const nWord = str.substr(0, position).split(/\W+/g).length;
    const r = new RegExp(`(?=((\\w+)\\W*){${nWord}})`, 'g');
    const segs = r.exec(str);
    if (!segs || !segs.length) {
        return null;
    }
    return r.exec(str)[2];
}
```

Perhaps someone can optimize this further?

Comment: [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a useful stack exchange for you if you're looking to improve somehting that's already working :)

Comment: A lot of overhead splitting  substring from 0 to position each time. Better to loop from position backwards by 2 to find a boundary `/\W(\w)/` then substring that postion to the end to find the forward end of word `/\w\b/`

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking! But since I'm here I thought I'd ask 1. how exactly to do so. 2. if there any more efficient ways.